# How to enforce a node version when running tests with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

When running tests with Jest, how can I enforce a minimum node version?

Similar to `engines` in package.json I want to be able to tell Jest `node: >=10` for example.

Comment: What exactly does this mean? Are you trying to make Jest bail out with error if Node version is less than 10?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If my jest tests are dependent on a feature that is only available in node >=10 I want to bail with an explicit message to say "Hey you're going to need node >=10 to run these tests." Rather than some potentially cryptic error.